# Debugging in MATLAB pmode

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, spmd

Is it possible to use debugging commands like dbstep and dbquit etc in the MATLAB [pmode](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/pmode.html) ?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do that. I'm afraid your best bet is to use `disp` or `fprintf` statements to track the program flow.